# How to send Json String using REST to java webservice in Parameter in android?

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, rest

Fiends, i sending JSON String with three parameters to java web service method. but on java side method cant print in console.  Please guide me what i have to change from below code?

```
String json = "";
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Prepare a request object
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("name", "ghanshyam");
            jsonObject.put("country", "India");
            jsonObject.put("twitter", "ghahhd");

            json = jsonObject.toString();

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
            se.setContentType("application/json");

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            System.out.println(json);

            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            httpGet.se
            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
            //httpPost.addHeader( "SOAPAction", "application/json" );
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            //String s = doGet(url).toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: if you post you complete code may be we can help you. But why you prepare request in POST and GET at the same time??? HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

Comment: you should use a library like volley or retrofit for painless api calling.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to post the json to Java web-service: and get the resopnse as a string.

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("name", "ghanshyam");
    json.put("country", "India");
    json.put("twitter", "ghahhd");

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8"));
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse httpresponse = client.execute(post);
    HttpEntity entity = httpresponse.getEntity();
    InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
    String result = convertStreamToString(stream);
```

and Your convertStremToString() method will be as follows:

```
    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try
        {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            } 
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                is.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Sir, Can you define me what is "client".

Comment: oops!! sorry . client is your HttpClient object. write another one line at the starting like:
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

Comment: Brother, its gives NoResponseheader error on server site.

Comment: how are you consuming the parameters at the server side. what is the code?

Comment: import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
(attherate)Path("/GauizzWebServiceForAndroid")
public class GauizzWebServiceForAndroid {   
    (at the rate)GET
    (at the rate)POST 
    (at the rate)Path("/responsePrint") 
    (at the rate)Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String responsePrint(String json){    
        String demoString = "prakash";
        System.out.println(json);
      
        return demoString;
         

    }
}

Comment: please give me more idea.

Comment: can't understand what have you written here.